# what is wrong in my relativelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hello everybody this is my first post here. I'm begginner in android devlopping.
I'm trying to do a listview and my list item should look likes:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/e3_0_1_184562_20150331100346" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:padding="5dp" >
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
            android:layout_above="@+id/dscription">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Product"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Distance"
                android:text="@string/shear"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Product"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/merk"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dscription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/thoor"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#888" />
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/bottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_p"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/price_p"
                android:text="@string/sheor"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#888" />
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price_p"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/name_p"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/mir"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need it to looks like that
distance , product
describtion
price , seller

the distance and the product in the first line, distance in left side and product name in right side.
second line , the long desctibtion of the product.
third line (the last), I want to show the price in the left side and the seller in the right side

it doesn't work and it writes:
Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

in the error log it writes 'listitem_deal.xml Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout'

thank you and sorry.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: it doesn't work and it writes:
Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Comment: And what exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Is the app crashing? Does the layout look different from what you want it to look? We need a detailed description of the exact problem otherwise we cannot give you a proper answer.

Comment: at the Graphical Layout it doesn't show a layout at all!

Comment: At the graphical layout? You mean in the preview window in your IDE?

Comment: yes. I don't know what IDE is but it doesn't show preview in the graphical layout

Comment: IDE is the application you use to write programs. The preview windows never work well and even if they do they are basically useless. Just concentrate on the xml and test your layout on a real device or emulator when you are finished.

Comment: But one thing I can say about your layout is that is is unnecessarily complex. You can build the same layout which just one `RelativeLayout` around an `ImageView` and five `TextView`s. [**Click here for reference**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

Answer (score 1):

> what is wrong in my relativelayout?

**Answer :** Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

**Now, what does that mean?**

Look at `TextView android:id="@+id/Product` and `TextView android:id="@+id/Distance"`

What are you doing is setting up `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Distance"` *on Product* and `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Product"` *on Distance*.

So what Android does is look at `Product` first and ask, where should I position this? Right of `Distance` - okay so I'll look at `Distance` and set `Product`. But `Distance` is positioned Left of `Product`. So I have to look where the `Product` is... and so on. Do you see how it goes in circle? (there is same error with `name_p` and `price_p`)

That's what that error looks for and doesn't allow you to position it this way.

Also, to correct

> The preview windows never work well and even if they do they are basically useless.

from comments - the preview feature is working just fine most of the time. This error should be raised on real device as well, not only on IDE.

Answer (score 0):

To create a ListVew  you need one ListView item, a structure to contain your data and one adapter to pass these data from the data source to the ListView.

Add the ListView from the layout manager(XML).

Good way to contain the data is to write your custom data class and store it in array or in others kind of structuress.

If your data class just contain one property you want to show use ArrayAdapter else you have to implement your own adapter.

You can use one Loader to query the data from the SqlLite database.

Here you can find more details:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html